# iPhone - Editing UITextField Moving Other Views to the Right

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitextfield, alignment

In my initial view controller that is loaded, one of my subviews is a UITextField. I have other subviews of the main view as well (i.e. four labels, one pickerview, and two buttons). When I try to edit the textfield, all of the other subviews shift to the right. I have no idea why this is happening. I have no code even applying to what happens while editing the textfield. But, I do have some code that serves to align all of my subviews (including the textfield). Here is that code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.stopPickerView.dataSource = self;
    self.stopPickerView.delegate = self;
    selectedEntry=@"";
    self.inputField.delegate=self;

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.



}

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{

    int width=self.view.bounds.size.width;
    int height=self.view.bounds.size.height;

    headingLabel.frame=CGRectMake(headingLabel.frame.origin.x, headingLabel.frame.origin.y,self.view.bounds.size.width-self.view.bounds.size.width/5, headingLabel.frame.size.height);
    headingLabel.center=CGPointMake(width/2,height/9);


    stopPickerView.center=CGPointMake(width/2, height/5);
    setStop.center=CGPointMake(width/2, height/2.2);
    orLabel.center=CGPointMake(width/2, height/1.7);
    wakeUpLabelOne.frame=CGRectMake(wakeUpLabelOne.frame.origin.x, wakeUpLabelOne.frame.origin.y,self.view.bounds.size.width-self.view.bounds.size.width/2, self.view.bounds.size.height-self.view.bounds.size.height/19.2);


          wakeUpLabelOne.center=CGPointMake(width/3.5, height/1.4);
    NSLog(@"%f",wakeUpLabelOne.frame.size.width);
    wakeUpLabelTwo.center=CGPointMake(width/1.1, height/1.4);
    inputField.center=CGPointMake(width/1.5, height/1.4);
    finalSetButton.center=CGPointMake(width/2, height/1.2);
    [wakeUpLabelTwo adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth];


}

- (int)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
    return 1;
}

- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {

    selectedEntry = [_pickerData objectAtIndex:row];

}

// The number of rows of data
- (int)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    return _pickerData.count;
}

// The data to return for the row and component (column) that's being passed in
- (NSString*)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    return _pickerData[row];
}

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [inputField resignFirstResponder];
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return NO;
}
```

If you have any ideas to why this is happening or you would like more information, just leave it in the comments.

Comment: In what block did you placed that frame configurations? Kindly provide complete code as much as possible. And if you don't mind me asking, couldn't you just use constraints for keeping your views align?

Comment: @Teffi I placed the frame configurations in the viewDidAppear block. I added more code above (but I am not sure it will be helpful). Also, I tried using constraints but I couldn't get it to work properly on all of the screen sizes. Thank you so much for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out why this was happening. For some reason, putting my frame configurations in the viewDidAppear method was a bad idea and was messing something up. The fix to this was to just put my frame configurations in the viewDidLayoutSubviews method instead. The problem was immediately fixed.